# does a PHP page with includes get compiled and sent as one page?

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP page where the header and footer are PHP includes.

I want to know if there is any possibility of the includes loading asynchronously - or does PHP gather all the files required, compile them and send them as one file?

The reason I ask is that I've seen an interesting PHP app that seemed to keep the connection open and do things in sequence before closing the connection - I wondered if that's what happens with includes.

PHP version is 5.3.6

EDIT:
What I actually want is for the page to load all at once, to prevent my layout mashing as each bit loads. Sorry to any who misunderstood this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to receive all the page at once you need to use ob_start() and ob_end_flush(). Do something like:

```
ob_start();
...
write all your outputs
...
ob_end_flush();
```

This will force the server to buffer the output until the whole page is prepared.

Good luck!

Comment: in hindsight, after reading all the answers and comments, this is what i want to do. i'll update the question to make it more clear, sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

PHP does gather and compile them; everything goes to the browser as a single document. If you don't want this, you'll have to do something with XMLHTTPRequest on the frontend

Comment: @jammypeach - actually be careful here. My experience is that PHP does NOT send everything at once. See my second response below if you want to receive everything at once.

Answer (score 2):

Generally any output will be output as it is generated.

```
echo 'A';
sleep(1000);
echo 'B';
sleep(1000);
echo 'C';
```

This slowly outputs "ABC". Includes are included when they are encountered, the same way `echo` outputs anything at that specific point. It's all in order, never asynchronously.

A web server *may* buffer all output before sending any of it to the client. In the above example, you'd receive "ABC" all together after 2 seconds of nothing.

Comment: Good answer, +1.  It also may buffer *some* of the output.  In addition, most browsers will buffer some before displaying.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following architecture when loading a page on my application:

index.php

```
<script src="path/to/js/lib/jslib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

window.addEvent('load', function()
{
    BuildPg(PgStatus); //PgStatus is a variable I use in a state machine to build different pages
});

<form>
<div id="DivPgTop"></div>
<div id="DivPgMiddle"></div>
<div id="DivPgBottom"></div>
</form>
```

This is the entire index.php

In my jslib.js I have functions like:

```
function BuildPg(Pg) {
    BuildPgTop(Pg);
    BuildPgMiddle(Pg);
    BuildPgBottom(Pg);
}

function BuildPgTop(Pg) {
    var Content="";
    if (Pg == 1) {
        Content = function_a(); // function_a builds the top of the page
    else if (Pg == 2) {
        Content = function_b();
    etc...
    }

    document.getElementById("DivPgTop").innerHTML = Content; //here is where I load the top of the page
}
```

And I do the same for the other parts of the page Middle and Bottom.

Using this framework, if you changed my BuildPg() function to something like:

```
function BuildPg(Pg) {
    BuildPgTop(Pg);
    sleep(foo);
    BuildPgMiddle(Pg);
    sleep(bar);
    BuildPgBottom(Pg);
}
```

Your user would experience the top of the page loading first, a delay, the middle of the page, another delay, and the bottom.

And if you change the order of the function calls you could even have the bottom of the page load first, then the middle and the top.

I hope this makes sense. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

PHP sends a single document. What you want to do is achieved with something called AJAX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Basically you write some JavaScript code that uses XMLHTTPRequest object to connect to the server and download some extra info.

Comment: Actually I don't think you need Ajax. I am able to reproduce what the op wants without using it (see my response below). In my experience PHP builds the page as it outputs stuff (unless you force it to buffer the output).

Comment: what i want is to be sure that my page will always be sent to the browser as a full page, not as 3 parts that are sent as they are loaded - this is so that my layout doesn't look horrible when loading, thats all.

Comment: @jammypeach - oh... I completely misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to reproduce the functionality of loading parts of the page at different times. See my second answer below for a way to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, me too, I thought you were trying to replicate that page's behavior.